# need instruction on this readme file

Tags: lisp, common-lisp

I am trying to run this code according to this read me file, but I am having trouble to execute the second line, I dont know what it is, is it the command line code in the terminal or just commands in the lisp listener? Or is it a package or something?

Can anybody give some help on how to running it？

To run the simulator, start lisp and execute the following commands in the listener:

```
(load "~/XXX/YYY/models/ZZZ/ZZZ-module.lisp")
:cm :ZZZ-module :propagate
(initialize-simulator "XXX/YYY/models/ZZZ/data/test/<config>.lisp" <controller-name> <keyword-args>)
```

Comment: what program are you trying to run?

Comment: it is a simulator which could simulate some actions of the robot, i dont understand the second line, everytime when i type them into my lisp listener, i would always get result like this:

Comment: [2] cl-user(6):  :cm :ZZZ-module :propagate
         Error: Module :ZZZ-module is not defined.

Answer (score 3):

This looks like GBBopen.

```
:cm :ZZZ-module :propagate
```

`:cm` is a REPL command. This is an extension for the normal REPL and is provided by GBBopen. You should also be able to use the `compile-module` function instead. See: [compile-module](http://gbbopen.org/hyperdoc/ref-compile-module.html).